# org-sparse-tree on multiple keywords

Tags: org-mode, keyboard-macros

I currently have a keyboard shortcut bound to `C-c t` that shows me all of the NEXTACTION items I have, no matter what headline level they're at. It works by using a kbd macro wherein I just typed `C-c / N <RET>`, and that was enough to fill in everything I needed.

But now I would like that same shortcut to also show me WAITING items. I tried just recording the whole macro of `C-c / NEXCTACTION|WAITING <RET>`, and assigning that, but for some reason it still seems to use the old macro. I don't have any idea what's going on there, it's almost like it's ignoring that I've changed the macro.

Looking at the function help for `org-sparse-tree` directly, it seems that it accepts optional arguments, but I can't find any documentation describing how to use the function.

In short, all I want is a single keyboard shortcut that gives an org-sparse-tree on two keywords at the same time. Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is the relevant part of my .emacs file:

```
(fset 'NEXTACTION-WAITING-org-tree
   [?\C-c ?/ ?T ?N ?E ?X ?T ?A ?C ?T ?I ?O ?N ?| ?W ?A ?I ?T ?I ?N ?G return])

(defun nextaction-org-tree-fun ()
  (progn
    (switch-to-buffer (find-file "~/orgfiles/personalorg.org"))
    (execute-kbd-macro (symbol-function 'NEXTACTION-WAITING-org-tree))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (nextaction-org-tree-fun)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to answer your last question.

Idea

```
F3 C-c / r NEXTACTION\|WAITING RET F4
C-xk b F5
```

Then F5 yields the desired sparse tree.

Comment: I considered doing this, but the "WAITING" case-insensitively matches my "Waiting: on x and y" phrases. Is there a way to make the regex case sensitive, or will I have to change my waiting phrase?

Comment: I don't know about the case-sensitivity at the moment.

Comment: What about C-c / T NEXTACTION|WAITING?

Comment: Curiously, typing it interactively in my org-mode buffer works, but defining it as a macro and then executing it does not. In fact, I even tried editing the macro to be sure that it was defined correctly. It is, but nevertheless it only shows me the NEXTACTION entries.

Comment: I can not confirm your observation. Could you provide a CME?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own problem with help from Marco Wahl by improving the regex a little:
In org-mode, these to-do keywords must be surrounded by a space on either side. In my case that differentiates them enough from other instances of similar words. This makes it easy to search for them using the emacs regex:

```
\s-\(NEXTACTION\|WAITING\|term3\|term4\|...\)\s-
```

Then, using emacs macros, type:

```
F3
C-c / r \s-\(NEXTACTION\|WAITING\|term3\|term4\|...\)\s-
RET
F4
```

Then the macro can be assigned, inserted, etc. as you like.